# Shabbos sustaining the world

Tags: shabbat, sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, creation

I heard from someone that “G-d created the world to last for six days plus the Shabbos. Then the Shabbos gives the world the spiritual energy to exist for another week and the cycle goes on continuously."

Does anyone where the source for this can be found?

Comment: This quotation appears to be adapted from the Artscroll Chumash, as nearly the exact same words are attributed to that volume (and thence to the Or HaChaim) by [Anshe Emes Parsha Page by Fred Toczek - Yisro](http://www.anshe.org/parsha/yisro.htm). This is a very weak question, since if it included the source for its premise, it would also, trivially, include its own answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This comes from the Ohr HaChaim commentary to כי ששת ימים עשה ה' את השמים ואת הארץ ([Shemos 31:17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9892#v=17)).  Ohr HaChaim notes that the verse does not say בששת ימים, in six days, but rather ששת ימים, six days.  Thus the verse reads "Six days Hashem created the world" meaning Hashem created it for a six day period, at the end of which it is renewed through the next Shabbos.

Comment: I couldn't find the source you mention in the Ohr HaChaim on Shemos 31:17 but I did find it in Bereishis 2:3